# SVA syntax: using $past with vector/array select i.e. $past(a[a_select])

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

Suppose I have the following:

```
$past(a[a_select])
```

Let's say in the current cycle `a_select` is '2' while it was '1' in the previous cycle.
Will the above evaluate to `a[2]` from previous cycle or to `a[1]` from previous cycle?

If it will be `a[1]` from previous cycle, what if I need it to be `a[2]` from the previous cycle -- i.e. I want the select to be from the current cycle, but it should select the bit from the vector value from the previous cycle. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `$past` is a system task that returns value of an expression n clock events before. If `a_select` is '2' in current cycle, then the expression `$past(a[a_select])` will return the value of `a[2]` from previous clock event.